# Prepend and append text to every line of a file in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've looked at numerous amounts of questions, all suggesting the same code and I have no idea why it doesn't work for me. I'm trying to prepend and append text to every line of a .txt file, using a .bat command. My code currently is

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (patchList.txt) do (
echo copy %%a>>output.txt
)
```

But upon running it nothing happens at all. Even if I try to output to the screen by getting rid of the output parameter, nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your `patchList.txt` is created/saved in Unicode encoding.

If `type patchList.txt` gives **readable output**, then the file contains [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and you could adjust your script as follows:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type patchList.txt') do (
    >>output.txt echo copy %%a
)
```

If `type patchList.txt` gives ***weird* output** with text *interspaced* by blanks or `□` white squares or other `�` replacement characters then the file does not contain BOM; then `Powershell` could help:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`
        powershell -Command Get-Content '%CD%\patchList.txt' -Encoding Unicode
                                 `) do (
    >>output.txt echo copy %%a
)
```

Or, better, **switch to `powershell` at all**! 
If `powershell` is not acceptable for some reason then we could utilize `find` command which can read Unicode files: try

```
< patchList.txt find "."
```

Please **note** that `"."` (full stop) above **is not a regex-like pattern nor a wildcard** so there might be difficult to determine all-lines matching character.

Comment: I figured this out just minutes before your answer,  but thank you for explaining it.